# Selecting a text box and writing a number in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium-webdriver, cypress, selenium-ide

I currently have two textboxs in which I'm suppose to enter the number. The problem I"m currently having is that my cypress code isn't able to select this text box. In addition, my second text box seems to be similar html tag. So how would I tell it to select the second one.

```
<input role="spinbutton" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="999" class="ant-input-number-input" autocomplete="off" max="999" min="0" step="1" value="">
```

```
<input role="spinbutton" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="999" class="ant-input-number-input" autocomplete="off" max="999" min="0" step="1" value="">
```

Code:

```
cy.get('.ant-input-number-input').click().text(25);
```

I want it to select the text box and I want to be able to write something. In addition, not sure how to select the second text box when the html tag is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use eq(n). For example:

```js
//select the first textbox
cy.get('[role="spinbutton"].ant-input-number-input').eq(0).type("write something");

//select the second textbox
cy.get('[role="spinbutton"].ant-input-number-input').eq(1).type("write something");
```